# Should I make redirect-urls creating API service with Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, backend

I am new to web-development and creating APIs, so I have some misunderstandings. I am creating online-shop API, and already have registration system with email confirmation. So the logic is: When user sends post request to registration endpoint he recieves an url that consists of token and his ID, at the same time his account is created, but is_active status equals False. When he requests the page with the url, his is_active=True.

So, according to business-logic of my web-app, when user requests the page with the given url to confirm email, he is supposed to automatically login and be redirected to his personal profile endpoint. My question is: should I make redirections in DRF using redirect and reverse functions, or it is a task for fronted developers?

Sorry if question seems to be silly, I am just learning.
Thanks in advance

Just want to clarify my mind, if it is ok to make redirects in backend development, or it is supposed to be done by frontend developers.

Comment: Does this mean, the user is not able to login to the system unless it has verified itself (using the link provided)? Will this token be valid forever?

Comment: Yes. I mean when is_active=False the user is not able to login. As for token, I haven't decided already, but I assume it will be valid forever

Answer (score 0):

#### One solution could be:

1. Send a unique code to the user email address with link to login page of the frontend.

```
http://web.xxx.xx/login?code=xxxx
```

2. Make user submit it's login credentials along with the code from the email address

```bash
curl http://api.xxx.xxx/login -d username xxx -d password xxx -d code xxx
```

3. Inside your Login API, make a conditional statement. If a user is not active yet and the login data contains code, check if the code is valid and belongs to the same user
4. Authenticate user only if the code is valid, otherwise do not let it in.

IMO, auth token should only be provided after a the login is verified. Otherwise those tokens could be mis-used.